# “The selected boot device failed” when attempting to install Ubuntu on my XPS

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, live-usb, xps

Atm, my Ubuntu 18.10 distribution is burning. I can not install any packages as I wrecked the `apt` part, and many programs are either broken or not installed correctly. Thus, I figured the easiest solution would do a clean install of Ubuntu 20.10. Here is a screenshot with more details

[image]

As I do not have an LTS version directly upgrading did not work, I tried a few hacks to make it work, and it was probably this that broke my `apt`. After some work, I was able to create a bootable USB stick with the 20.10 LTS ISO of Ubuntu. I did it as follows

```
sudo umount /dev/sda1

sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sda1
  
sudo dd bs=4M if=PATH/ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sda1 status=progress oflag=sync
```

However, when trying to boot it, I only receive the following message:

```
The selected boot device failed. Press <Enter> to continue.
```

I must reiterate **I can see the USB fine in my filesystem. I also have no problems writing to it. Yet, booting from it fails.**
What I've tried so far:

- Disable fast boot in Windows
- Disable Secure Boot in the BIOS settings
- Searched for an option to enable Legacy booting, and enabled it
- Used two different USB drives
- Formated the USB to FAT32
- Tried using both USB ports (one on each side) on my computer.
- Also tried "Kubuntu" (also 20.10).
- On my work computer, an HP Probook both USB's boot fine, whether it was Kubuntu Or Ubuntu.

None of these helped me:

- [“The selected boot device failed” when attempting to boot a Live USB on my device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677089/the-selected-boot-device-failed-when-attempting-to-boot-a-live-usb-on-my-devic)
- [“selected bootable device failed” error dual boot ubuntu alongside windows8.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473663/selected-bootable-device-failed-error-dual-boot-ubuntu-alongside-windows8-1)
- [Dual Booting in HP Laptop "Selected boot device failed to boot" Error](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2256042)

Do you have any idea why the USB won't boot or what can be done about it? The USB seems fine as I can boot from it from another machine, however, I have no idea why I suddenly can not boot from my XPS 15.

Comment: Use sdX without the number at the end. You don't need to care about any partitions on the pendrive (no FAT or anything). Also, is the PATH a real path? Just to add, Ubuntu 18.10 is no longer supported that's the reason you cannot install packages.

Comment: @lev258 Why would this matter? I am not saying it does not. But as I said the USB boots fine on other machines. Thus, I doubt I have created the live ISO incorrectly. I just changed it to `PATH` in the post, when creating it I used the actual location of the ISO file.

Comment: When you use dd on a disk, it will create partitions according to the ISO. If I remember right, Ubuntu ISO makes at least two. I don't know the reason but it might be related to being able to do Legacy and UEFI capable boot (both of them). If you force it on a definite partition (sda1) it probably won't be able to make things ideal.

Comment: Your `dd`command seems odd. `/dev/sda` is the first disk in the computer, normally an interior disk. Are you sure that your USB is mounted as `/dev/sda`? What other disks/SSDs are connected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/) and [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/1190764/)